# How to count the functional size of this with FPA?

Tags: function-points

"The user click in one action button that trigger the system to read a file from a second system and send it to a third system. "
(Three systems interacting)

I counted:

1. One EIF - External Interface File.
2. One External Input - Reading the file from another system .
3. One External Output - Send the file to the third system.

Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's right the counting above.